# Restrict numbers from being entered on an EditText

Tags: java, android

I need to restrict the user for entering Numbers (0-9) in an EditText and allow every other character from the keyboard.

The following code is not working on the following scenario.

If the user enters an alphabet and then a number, the editText becomes empty.

```
InputFilter withoutNumberFilter = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i))) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};

editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { withoutNumberFilter });
```

Comment: "The following code is not working"  How is it not working? What exactly do you expect it to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: It should allow all other characters except numbers on the range 0-9 . It should allow alphabets ,  special characters , Chinese characters , etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `isLetter()` method to compare

```
if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i))) {
   return "";
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to do `!Character.isLetter()`?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update your condition to:

`if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i)))`

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regex to replace all digits:

```
source = source.replaceAll("[0-9]","")
```

If you want to do it as the user is entering input, then just input this statement after every action event.

Answer (score 0):

Extending you class might help and implement a listener. You then can re-use your extended JTextField in other Forms.

Just a simple example.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MyJTextField extends JTextField implements KeyListener {

    public MyJTextField() {
        super();
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    boolean found = false;

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

        char c = arg0.getKeyChar();
        char[] cs = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

        for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
            if (c == cs[i]) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

        if (found) {
            String text = getText();
            setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
            found = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // No action.
    }
}
```

Any other comments are welcome.